# How can i delete the repeated numbers from a file?

Tags: python

i need to delete numbers that are iterated more than once .. if i know the repeated numbers already. Should i have two files .. one for the real numbers i have " data .txt ".  and the other contains the numbers which are iterated " columns.txt" .. it is just for searching quickly the repeated numbers – As the file is too huge to delete it manually so i saved the repeated numbers in a file .. how can i make right loop for searching from a file to another file and if it find it .. just delete the repeated and keep one of them only
the code i tried to implement like

```
infile = "/home/user/Desktop/data.txt"
outfile = "/home/user/Desktop/new.txt"
numbers="/home/user/Desktop/columns.txt"
with open(infile) as fin, open(outfile, "w+") as ft:
    for line in fin:
        for number in numbers:
                line = line.replace(number, "")
        ft.write(line)
```

but still have a problem .. the loop deleted all numbers that are iterated and i need to keep one of them only .. not delete all repeated

```
data.txt 

53.74270106
60.45828786
50.08396881
119.2588545
119.2588545
119.2588545
119.2588545
119.2588545
119.2588545
119.2588545
8.391147123
3.998351513
```

it should be like this

```
53.74270106
60.45828786
50.08396881
119.2588545
8.391147123
3.998351513
```

i need to delete the number if it appears only sequentially

Comment: Please,post your traceback too.

Comment: i edit the result i got .. the loop deleted all numbers that are iterated and i need to keep one of them only .. not delete all repeated

Comment: show a small sample of your `infile` and `numbers` you have

Comment: i edit the post .. i got from my code deleting all 119.2588545 from the file

Comment: `numbers="/home/user/Desktop/columns.txt"` you have mentioned you have a list of duplicate numbers as well

Comment: yes i have .. it is just for searching quickly the repeated numbers

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are on python 3.6+ then this solution will work for you. This way you dont need to have a list where you already know the repeated numbers, python will do that for you.

If you are not using python 3.6+ then change `dict.fromkeys` to `collections.OrderedDict.fromkeys`.

```
with open('data.txt') as file:
    lines = dict.fromkeys(line.strip() for line in file)

with open('out.txt', 'w') as file:
    file.writelines('\n'.join(lines))
```

Output

```
53.74270106
60.45828786
50.08396881
119.2588545
8.391147123
3.998351513
```

Comment: i forger the usage of dictionary .. so many thanks for you

Answer (score 0):

I think the set is better

```
a_set = set()
with open ('data2.txt') as f:
    for line in f:
        a_set.add(line)
print(a_set)
```

```
{'3.998351513', '50.08396881\n', '60.45828786\n', '119.2588545\n', '8.391147123\n', '53.74270106\n'}
```

Comment: this does not maintain order